# My php is showing validation errors but JS isnt

Tags: php, validation

I am in the early stages of making a registration page for my website. However, the basic form I have created is being validated by javascript and php to ensure the right data will be entered. Even when the javascript is showing no errors and allowing the form to submit, the PHP errors are still being flagged and stopping it. below is the code for the php and html form. Any help will be greatly appreciated, these things are normally a lot easier than anticipated but its driving me crazy as it isnt showing any syntax errors just the errors that i have set up for the user.
The include files just have the mysql password and some basic functions for checking phone numbers.
Thanks in advance
HTML

```
<?php require_once("functions.inc"); ?>
```

```
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="register.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    <title>A Form</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="userForm" method="POST" action="register-process.php">
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration Information</legend>
                <div id="errorDiv">
                    <?php 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['error']) && isset($_SESSION['formAttempt'])){
                            unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
                            print "errors encountered<br>\n";
                            foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $error) {
                                print $error . "<br>\n";
                            }//end foreach
                        } // end if
                    ?>
                </div>

                 <label for="fname">First Name:* </label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="fnameError">First Name is required</span>
                <br>

                 <label for="name">Last Name:* </label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="lnameError">Last Name is required</span>
                <br>

                <label for="email">Email Address:* </label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="emailError">Email is required</span>
                <br>

                <label for="password1">Password:* </label>
                <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1">
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="password1Error">Password is required</span>
                <br>

                <label for="password2">Varify Password:* </label>
                <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="password2Error">Password's do not match</span>
                <br>

                <label for="addr">Address: </label>
                <input type="text" id="addr" name="addr">
                <br>

                <label for="city">City: </label>
                <input type="text" id="city" name="city">
                <br>

                <label for="state">State: </label>
                <select name="state" id="state">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="WI">Winconsin</option>
                </select>
                <br>

                <label for="zip">ZIP: </label>
                <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                <br>

                <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label>
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="phoneError">Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx</span>
                <br>
                <br>

                <label for="work">Number Type:</label>
                <input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="phoneType" id="work" value="work">
                <label class="radioButton" for="work">Work</label>
                <input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="phoneType" id="home" value="home">
                <label class="radioButton" for="home">Home</label>
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan phoneTypeError" id="phoneTypeError">Please Choose an option.</span>
                <br>

                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

PHP register process.php

```
    <?php

require_once('functions.inc');

//prevent access if they havent submitted the form!!
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    die(header("location: register.php"));
}

$_SESSION['formAttempt'] = true;

if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}

$_SESSION['error'] = array();

$required = array("fname","lname", "email", "password1", "password2");                   

//check required fields!
foreach ($required as $requiredField) {
    if (!isset($_POST[requiredField]) || $_POST[$requiredField] == "") {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = $requiredField . " is required.";
    }
}

if (!preg_match('/^[\w .]+$/',$_POST['fname'])) {
    $_SESSION['error'][] = "Name must be letters and numbers only.";
}
if (!preg_match('/^[\w .]+$/',$_POST['lname'])) {
    $_SESSION['error'][] = "Name must be letters and numbers only.";
}

if (isset($_POST['state']) && $_POST['state'] != "") {
    if (!isValidState($_POST['state'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a valid state";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['zip']) && $_POST['zip'] != "") {
    if (!isValidZip($_POST['zip'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "ZIP code error";
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] != "") {
    if (!preg_match('/^[\d]+$/', $_POST['phone'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Phone numbner should be digits only.";
    } else if (strlen($_POST['phone']) < 10 ) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Phone number should be at least 10 digits.";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['phoneType']) || $_POST['phoneType'] == "") {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a phone type.";
    } else {
        $validPhoneTypes = array("work","home");
        if (!in_array($_POST['phoneType'], $validPhoneTypes)) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a valid phone type";
        }
    }
}

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $_SESSION['error'][] = "Invalid e-mail address!";
}

if ($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Passwords do not match";
}

//Final Disposition
if (count($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
    die (header("Location: register.php"));
} else {
    if (registerUser($_POST)) {
        unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
        die(header("Location: success.php"));
    } else {
        error_log("problem registering user: {$_POST['email']}");
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Problem registering account";
        die(header("Location: register.php"));
    }
}
```

The extension is the rest of the process php file, i have commented where the errors are coming from.... Thanks Again..

```
if (count($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
    die (header("Location: register.php"));
} else {
    if (registerUser($_POST)) {
        unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
        die(header("Location: success.php"));
    } else {
        error_log("problem registering user: {$_POST['email']}"); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS COMNING FROM
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Problem registering account";
        die(header("Location: register.php"));
    }
}

function registerUser($userData) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        error_log("Cannot connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        return false;
    }
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    //Check for an existing user
    $findUser = "SELECT id from Customer where email = '{$email}'";
    $findResult = $mysqli->query($findUser);
    $findRow = $findResult->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($findRow['id']) && $findRow['id'] != "") {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "A user with that email already exists";
        return false;
    }

    $lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);

    $cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password1']);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($cryptedPassword);

    if (isset($_POST['addr'])) {
        $street = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['addr']);
    } else {
        $street = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    } else {
        $city = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['state'])) {
        $state = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
    } else {
        $state = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['zip'])) {
        $zip = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['zip']);
    } else {
        $zip = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    } else {
        $phone = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['phoneType'])) {
        $phoneType = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phoneType']);
    } else {
        $phoneType = "";
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO Customer (email,create_date,password,last_name,first_name,street,city,state,zip,phone,phone_type) " . "VALUES ('{$email}',NOW(),'{$password}','{$lastname}','{$firstname}'" . ",'{$street}','{$city}','{$zip}','{$phone}','{$phoneType}')";
    if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
        $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        error_log("inserted {$email} as ID {$id}");
        return true;
    } else {
        error_log("Problem inserting {$query}");
                $_SESSION['error'][] = "HERE"; // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS COMNING FROM
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: BTW this code is wrong: **die(header("Location: success.php"));** should get changed to **header("Location: success.php"); exit;**

Comment: If that is all of your code which I am assuming it is, I dont see `session_start();` anywhere.

Comment: Which fields are giving you trouble? all of them?

Comment: @bub "wrong" is a bit of an exaggeration. it will die printing the output of the header command - which is nothing.

Comment: You say "the PHP errors are still being flagged and stopping it". What are the PHP errors? According to your code comments, it looks like your query is failing. Post the database error and query if that is the case.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston I am getting "Problem inserting INSERT INTO Customer...." in my php error_log. the query must be where it is going wrong. and for the php errors, i have sorted some since the first post but when the conditional is failing its adding a error string to $_SESSION['error'] and therefore displaying. If it is the query which is looking likely what could it be?

Comment: @Gmiles your error isn't in your form validation, it is in your query because `if ($mysqli->query($query))` is returning `false`. After your error_log Problem inserting.., add `error_log($mysqli->error);` so you can find the error

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston [17-Sep-2015 20:15:51 Europe/Berlin] Problem inserting INSERT INTO Customer (email,create_date,password,last_name,first_name,street,city,state,zip,phone,phone_type) VALUES ('grant@test.com',NOW(),'$1$4./.5P3.$6F/uTWrYGGnb6gNrIvuDK1','Miles','Grant','5 Down town','sheerness','12345','0123456789','work')
[17-Sep-2015 20:15:51 Europe/Berlin]
problem registering user: grant@test.com //this is the error i log in the script

Comment: Where is `problem registering user: grant@test.com` coming from? That is not a mysql error.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston that is me adding an error using error_log earlier on. Thank you for your help, when i logged the error i could see that i have 11 fields and only 10 values, one of the values wasnt in the query. you wouldnt believe i spent 4 hours today reading over and over again. Thank again

Comment: You're welcome. Make it a habit to always log `mysqli::$error` in your failure conditions. I added an answer while you were posting your last comment because I found the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has a bug in it. Column count isn't the same as value count. You forgot to pass in `$state`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Customer (email,create_date,password,last_name,first_name,street,city,state,zip,phone,phone_type) " . "VALUES ('{$email}',NOW(),'{$password}','{$lastname}','{$firstname}'" . ",'{$street}','{$city}','{$state}', '{$zip}','{$phone}','{$phoneType}')";
    if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
        $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        error_log("inserted {$email} as ID {$id}");
        return true;
    } else {
        error_log("Problem inserting {$query}");
        error_log("Problem inserting {$mysqli->error}"); // log the error
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "HERE"; // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS COMNING FROM
        return false;
    }
```